# Как вызвать функцию класса из переменной?

Tags: c++, ооп

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом, можно в C++ сохранить функцию класса в переменную, и затем вызвать её из основного тела программы?

Если делать всё просто в main, без разделение на классы, то всё работает. Я же хочу сделать именно в разных файлах.
Как бы я не пытался придумать, у меня выходит ошибка:

```
non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Пробую как-то так:

```
//Class.h:
class Class
{
public:
  typedef void(Class::*funcType)();
  funcType func;
  void test();
};

//Class.cpp:
#include "Class.h"
#include <iostream>
Class::Class()
{
  func = Class::test;
}
void Class::test()
{
  std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
}

//Program.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"
void mian()
{
  Class1 c;
  c.func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: К тому же указатель на метод немного отличается от указателя на функцию. Ему нужен объект, к которому этот указатель на метод мы можем применить. И тогда получится такая штука `(c.*c.func)();`

Comment: Пробовал ставить * и & в различных комбинациях, это не изменяло ошибку. Что-то не пойму, как использовать (c.*c.func)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так.

```
#include <iostream>

class OBJ
{
public:

    int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};
int main()
{
    OBJ obj;

    int (OBJ::*fuu)(int,int);


    fuu = &OBJ::add;


    std::cout << (obj.*fuu)(2,3) ;
   return 0;
}
```

А что касается вашего примера, то так

```
#include <iostream>
class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
      func = &Class::test;
    }

  typedef void(Class::*funcType)();
  funcType func;
  void test()
  {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Class c;

  (c.*c.func)(); // achtung!!!
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Оно работает!

Comment: Прямо вообще большое спасибо! Сейчас потребовалось вызвать функцию другого класса из класса, и как раз подошёл Ваш первый пример!

Comment: @Wnev посмотрите комментарий Drawn Raccoon, он вам ответил еще до меня.

Comment: Да, спасибо Drawn Raccoon за попытку помочь, но я не додумался поставить & как говорил Abyx, и ему спасибо. Если бы совместил их комментарии, то ошибок бы не было.